# jQuery click action to toggle but prevent toggle while clicking link in div

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I have a div that has a click toggle action that when user clicks that div it will toggle the class of a span from hidden to visible. The problem is within that I have an href that triggers a popup modal, when you click that popup modal link it triggers the toggle action. I am looking for a suggestion to prevent toggle when clicking that link. Any help is much appreciated!

jQuery:

```
jQuery(".clickable-div").on( 'click', function() {
jQuery(this).find('span.hidden-desc').toggle();  
});
```

inside ".clickable-div" there is an href with the following

`<span id="popup-cont"><a id="popup-link" href="#popup">VIEW FULL LIST</a></span>`

Answer (score 0):

You want to use `stopPropagation` on the event that is triggered when you click the Link within your span. That prevents the event from bubbling up to parent DOM Elements in your HTML structure.

```js
$('.clickable').on('click', function() {
  $(this).find('span').toggleClass('hidden');
})

// Add stopPropagation() to the a Link within the span
$('.clickable > span > a').on('click', function( e ) {
    e.stopPropagation();
})
```

```css
.hidden {
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="clickable">
  Click me
  <span class="hidden">NOT SEEN <a href="#">Link</a></span>
</div>
```

Comment: worked with some minor adjustments, thank you for the help!